# How to arrange relationships in a matrix in concentric square fashion in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to arrange relationships in a matrix in concentric square fashion.?

here is the idea.

I've a couple of peoples and their relationships;

```
people = [
    {id:2332, person: 'jonathan', age: 20, type: 'origin'},
    {id:2311, person: 'maker', age: 34, type: 'relation'},
    {id:3423, person: 'toni', age: 23, type: 'relation'},
    {id:4523, person: 'lork', age: 65, type: 'sister'},
    {id:8756, person: 'caper', age: 34, type: 'relation'},
    {id:0983, person: 'april', age: 12, type: 'brother'},
    {id:1432, person: 'wisher', age: 45, type: 'friend'},
    {id:8736, person: 'kevin', age: 67, type: 'relation'},
    {id:9832, person: 'makeba', age: 23, type: 'friend'},
    {id:8923, person: 'ulbeth', age: 43, type: 'friend'},
    {id:0984, person: 'lapreth', age: 89, type: 'friend'},
    {id:1256, person: 'vlag', age: 76, type: 'friend'},
    {id:3409, person: 'lood', age: 42, type: 'relation'},
    {id:2342, person: 'kane', age: 35, type: 'uncle'},
    {id:3421, person: 'locket', age: 76, type: 'uncle'},
    {id:5423, person: 'cunnigan', age: 12, type: 'uncle'},
    {id:3343, person: 'mix', age: 76, type: 'relation'},
    {id:3409, person: 'pintola', age: 25, type: 'relation'},
    {id:0934, person: 'kudala', age: 54, type: 'relation'},
    {id:8412, person: 'lodask', age: 56, type: 'cousin'},
    {id:0784, person: 'late', age: 34, type: 'aunt'},
    {id:2316, person: 'kilem', age: 32, type: 'relation'},
    {id:9903, person: 'vloogi', age: 12, type: 'relation'},
]

relationships = [
    {source: 2332, target: 4523},
    {source: 2332, target: 3409},
    {source: 2332, target: 2311},
    {source: 2332, target: 9832},
    {source: 3409, target: 8923},
    {source: 1432, target: 3423},
    {source: 0983, target: 1256},
    {source: 0984, target: 9832},
    {source: 1256, target: 1256},
    {source: 8756, target: 8736},
    {source: 0983, target: 8756},
    {source: 9832, target: 0983},
    {source: 0983, target: 8412},
    {source: 0984, target: 1432},
    {source: 1256, target: 4523},
    {source: 8756, target: 8736},
    {source: 0983, target: 1256},
    {source: 9832, target: 3409},
        {source:2342, target: 3409},
    {source:3421, target: 3421},
    {source:5423, target: 1256},
    {source:3343, target: 3343},
    {source:3409, target: 8736},
    {source:0934, target: 1432},
    {source:8412, target: 8412},
    {source:0784, target: 0784},
    {source:2316, target: 0784},
    {source:9903, target: 9903},
]
```

here is the code for a 2d matrix:

```
var matrix = [];
for(var i=0; I<size; i++) {
    matrix[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<size; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = undefined;
    }
}
```

from the above matrix we find the central cell & assign its address `[i,j]` as the centre in the following code

```
      let center = this.getCentralCellAddressFromMatrix();

      function generate([cRow, cCol], space) {
        const topRow = Array.from(Array(space * 2 + 1), (_, i) => [
          cRow - space,
          cCol - space + i,
        ]);
        const bottomRow = Array.from(Array(space * 2 + 1), (_, i) => [
          cRow + space,
          cCol - space + i,
        ]);
        const leftCol = Array.from(Array(space * 2 + 1 - 2), (_, i) => [
          cRow - space + i,
          cCol - space,
        ]);
        const rightCol = Array.from(Array(space * 2 + 1 - 2), (_, i) => [
          cRow + space + i,
          cCol + space,
        ]);
        return [].concat(topRow, bottomRow, leftCol, rightCol);
      }
```

What I want to achieve it as follows:

1. first we fix the person with type 'origin' as the centre of the matrix.
2. then arrange his relationships in a concentric square like fashion around him. (note that we should consider a single strip of concentric cells (highlighted in blue below figure). if his relationships count is greater than the concentric cell number then move to next level... && so on...
3. once you finish his relationships.... move to the next level (i.e. relationships of the `'origin'` person's relationships. Again here you follow the same pattern as mentioned above (like keeping each of those relation as origin => then finding concentric square strips around that person && arrange it's relations in unoccupied cells around it... )
4. likewise we traverse the whole map till all relationships are arranged.

[image]

Comment: That's more than "a couple" (2).  Did you mean "a few", or, did I not understand?

Comment: Were did "uncle", "friend", etc. come from?
In `relationships`, it doesn't say what type of relationship.
There are 24 people and 28 relationships - doesn't seem to match-up, or, more details needed.

Comment: Use of 2D matrix is interesting.
When faced with similar project, I was thinking circles and lines.

Comment: the idea is to create a relation map. like a mind map... in a grid fashion. so that it looks well packed.

Comment: Please edit your previous question instead of deleting and re-posting it.

Comment: Will you use different colors?
Which is closer: a brother or a father or a son or a wife?
And a friend?
Second cousins that got married (their child is a third cousin of itself).
An uncle by marriage who adopted, with his wife/blood aunt, his deceased sister's daughter - is she a cousin?
How about multiple spouces?
These are questions I had to think about when attempting to implement my relationships program.

Comment: The closer ones will be those who are directly connected to the person with type: ```origin```.